# Handler support in Android 4

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

My application needs to support Android 4 and above.

I have a starting activity which only shows the icon and the name of the app. I wanna show it to user for 3 secs. The code below works perfectly fine on Android 5 and 6. However it crashes on Android 4.

Is Handler not supported on Android 4?

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Comment: Do you have any log error ?

Comment: Android Handlers have been there since API 1 according to the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) - perhaps there may be some clues in the error log. Please paste the error log so we can examine it.

Comment: Bad thing is, it also works on emulators. However, it crashes on real devices(tested on GM Discovery and Galaxy S3). Unfortunately, I have Marshmallow installed on my phone and I send my apk file to my friend to test it... @ishmaelmakitla

Comment: Did you test with an emulator running Android 4? My suspicion is that it might be whatever you are doing in the `run()` method and not necessarily the use of `Handler`. If at all possible, you could ask your friend to send you the logs.

Comment: Yes I tested it with the official emulator and as well as with genymotion emulators (versions are 4.1.1,4.2.2 and 4.4.2). In the run method, it just starts a new activity as the code I've written above. Nothing more. Is there a specific log folder that logs the crashes? I am new in Android so every single information is helpful. Thanks @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: We need the error log...otherwise everything here will be assumptions...